# Time.FixedTimeStep in Project Settings is disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, project-settings

How to change the Fixed Timestep in the project settings. It does not seem like I can set any value. Please see the screenshot attached!

[image]

Comment: Did you increase the horizontal size of `Project Settings`?

Comment: @HeejaeKim Thanks!!! I can see it now when the horizontal size is increased!